# Como fazer a tag <p> dividir um texto em sei la 4 linhas de poucos caracteres?

Tags: html

Como fazer a tag

dividir um texto em sei la 4 linhas de x caracteres ao inves da tag ir até o fim da linha da tela??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para realizar a quebra de linha de um texto em HTML você deve utilizar o elemento [`<br/>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) no final de cada linha. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```html
<p>
    Olá Mundo!<br>
    Este é apenas um simples exemplo de quebra de linha<br>
    Atenciosamente, eu.
</p>
```

Uma outra forma de realizar a quebra de linhas, é utilizando um elemento [`<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) para cada linha.

```html
<p>
    <div>Olá Mundo!</div>
    <div>Este é apenas um simples exemplo de quebra de linha</div>
    <div>Atenciosamente, eu.</div>
</p>
```

Em ambas as formas que eu apresentei, não é necessário quebrar a linha no código HTML como eu fiz, já que isso não vai fazer diferença nenhuma quando o navegador renderizar a página.

Logo você pode realizar a quebra de linha com os elementos escrevendo o texto em uma única linha no documento HTML.

```html
<p>
    Olá Mundo!<br>Este é apenas um simples exemplo de quebra de linha<br>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eae Hícaro, você pode quebrar linhas no seu parágrafo usando a tag 
.
Exemplo:

`<p> Primeira Linha <br> Segunda Linha <br> Terceira linha </p>`

Answer (score 0):

você pode dividir os textos com `<br />`. (seria o jeito mais grotesco).

Outras alternativas, é colocar o `<p>` dentro de `<div>` e estilizar com css a largura máxima.